# Sending and receiving file size successfully in C

Tags: c, file, file-transfer, filesize

I want to be able to send a file from the client to the server. I'm using TCP. I'm trying to use fseek and etc to get the size of the file because I want to be able to handle large files, and then send that amount of bytes of data as well as the files contents to the server. So far, according to my printf messages everything goes through and the file is created. However, the file created on the server is empty. There's obviously something wrong with the way I am sending it and receiving it via parameters or something, but I can't figure it out. Can someone please show me where I've gone wrong and how I can fix it because I'm so close!

Server part:

```
if(getFile){
         
                char *tmp = buf + 9;
                char filename2[MAX_BLOCK_SIZE];
                int length, x;
                long file_size = 0;
                FILE *fp;
                strcpy(filename2, tmp);
                printf("Server receiving file name...\n");
                //first 'read' receives the file name
                fp = fopen(filename2, "wb");
                if(fp == NULL){
                    printf("File could not be opened.\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                printf("Server receiving file...\n");
                while((x = read(sd, buf, sizeof(buf)) > 0)){ //second read now retrieving the file
                    printf("Server creating new file...\n");
                    fwrite(buf, 1, file_size, fp);
                }
            fclose(fp);
            printf("The server has received the requested document.\n");
         }
```

Client side:

```
 else if(putCommand){
            
            char *tmp = buf + 4;
            char filename[MAX_BLOCK_SIZE];
    
        long file_size;
            strcpy(filename, "filename ");
            strcat(filename, tmp);
            FILE *fp;
            printf("File name: %s\n", tmp);
            fp = fopen(tmp, "rb");
            if(fp == NULL){
                
                printf("ERROR: Requested file does not exist.\n");
                
            }
            else{
            printf("Client sending filename...\n");
            if ((nw = write(sd, filename, sizeof(filename)) < nr)){     //sending the file name to the client first
                printf("Error sending client's filename.\n");
            }
            
            //size_t file_size;
            printf("Client sending file...\n");
            fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
            long filesize = ftell(fp);
            fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
            
            while((file_size = fread(buf, 1, MAX_BLOCK_SIZE, fp)) > 0){ //sending the file
            
                if ((x = write(sd, buf, filesize) < 0)){
                    printf("Error sending client file.\n");
                }
            
            }
            fclose(fp);
            
            
            }
```

Comment: `if((x = read(sd, buf, sizeof(buf)) <= 0)){` `read` returns a negative number *on error*.

Comment: Also, on the server side you need to keep receiving until all bytes have been received. You can't assume a single `read` will get all the data.

Comment: Why not use `stat()` to get the size?

Comment: @kaylum I've changed it to a while loop, now edited in my code, so that it reads and write to file while the number of bytes received is greater than 0. But now it never seems to leave that loop

Comment: @Shawn I've found a few implementations of stat, but I haven't been able to integrate it properly. I should probably try that way again

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I have changed that to > 0, that is my mistake sorry

Comment: `while((x = read(sd, buf, sizeof(buf)) > 0))` makes no sense. You want to know how many bytes `read` was able to read, and *use that number*. That would be `while((x = read(sd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) { fwrite(buf, 1, x, fp); }` Note parentheses and the use of `x`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.I've made that change, thanks. My while loop doesn't seem to end and go on to display the print statement that verifies the document was copied. When I end the program via terminal, my copied document only has the first letter copied inside of it

Answer (score 2):

It is close to a typo. On the receiver side, you have:

```
long file_size = 0;
...
    while(...)
        ...
        fwrite(buf, 1, file_size, fp);
```

So you consistently write 0 byte.

The *standard* way is:

```
    while((x = read(sd, buf, sizeof(buf)) > 0)){ //second read now retrieving the file
        printf("Server creating new file...\n");
        fwrite(buf, 1, x, fp);     // write the number of bytes returned by previous read
    }
```

Last remark, I hope that `buf` is a true array and not a pointer...

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I've made these changes, and this same while loop on the receiving side never ends. When I end the program via terminal, the document created only has the FIRST letter inside it from the document I sent